# C++ map templates to other template, then to tuple

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

I'm working on some low level drivers and I thought I'd use C++ templates to spice it up.

In Verilog, you can define bitmasks using `[h:l]` notation where `h` is the high bit, `l` is the low bit. I have a data structure already defined for this:

```
uint16_t mask(uint8_t h, uint8_t l) {
  return h << 8 + l;
}
```

I'd like to memoize these bitmasks. Say I want to modify bits [7:4] of register R, if I've already read in R before hand I can just modify the old value of R before writing it, rather than sending out a new read request to my device.

To find the number of bytes needed for each memoization, I already have a function

`constexpr uint8_t requiredBytes(uint16_t mask)`

which returns the number of bytes needed to hold the mask.

Is there a way to static-time declare a memoization buffer for ease of analysis? (this will run on embedded platforms)

I assume I need a pipeline like below:

```
template <uint16_t... masks>
(1) V
Apply requiredBytes() to each mask in the template
(2) V
Convert each value from requirdBytes to a type (requiredBytes() = 1 => uint8_t, ...)
(3) V
Convert this list of types into a std::tuple<>
```

I know I can do transformation 2 using a series of template specializations, which leads to my question, how can we implement transformations 1 and 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that your step 2, which you've described as already a done deal, is something along the lines of

```
typename bytesType<n>::type
```

Where the template parameter `n` is the number of bytes, and this gives you the type via an appropriate specialization. If so, then this seems to be something along the lines of a straightforward pack expansion:

```
template <uint16_t ...masks>
using tuple_mask=std::tuple<typename bytesType<requiredBytes(masks)>::type...>;
```

`requiredBytes()` is a constexpr, this provides the parameter to `bytesType`, which gives you the type. Then, pack-expand it, and feed it into a `std::tuple` declaration.